# Synonym of "Barber Shop Pole"!

Tags: synonyms

Is there any **one word** synonym of Barbershop Pole? (Any **local word** perhaps that starts with 'B'?)

Any **one word** synonym will be fine BTW.

Comment: Fun fact: Another name for a Barber's Shop Pole is a "Marvy Pole"

Answer (score 2):

barbershoppole

[BloodCandyCane](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2013/10/bloody-history-barber-pole/)

There's a lot of concepts that don't have a one word synonym... congratulations you've found one!
"Barber's Pole" does not have any traditional synonyms (one word or otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

The term *barberpole* is used in [*barberpole illusion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barberpole_illusion).